# Sockets maintain socket open and just check the messages that the client is sending

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

What I am trying to do is just check the messages that the client is sending.
what I want is to maintain the socket that was created  open and just check the get message that the client send from time to time.

I am using `System.Net.Sockets` only, I want to make an implementation based on barkeley sockets.

Here is my code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;
namespace Socket_v1._0
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int BUFSIZE = 200;// Size of receive buffer
        private const int BACKLOG = 5; // O valor backlog define o número de pedidos de conexão que podem ser mantidos em espera sem serem aceites pela "system-call" accept.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int servPort = 8070; //port number

            Socket server = null;
            try
            {
                // Create a socket to accept client connections
                server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, servPort));
                server.Listen(BACKLOG);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se.ErrorCode + ": " + se.Message);
                Environment.Exit(se.ErrorCode);
            }
//for now the server socket is waiting for connections
            byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE]; // definir buffer
            int bytesRcvd = 0 ; // numero de bytes recebidos
            for (; ; )
            { // Run forever, accepting and servicing connections
                Socket client = null;
                try
                {

                    client = server.Accept(); // Get client connection
                    Console.Write("Handling client at " + client.RemoteEndPoint + " - ");

                    do {
                        bytesRcvd = client.Receive(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);
                        }while (true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

So the client send a http get from time to time, i want to see those messages,

for now for the first time this runs the string gets the http get, and because I am maintaining the socket open, I want to wait for the next message (`do{}(while(true))`).
it goes back to the client.receive, and stops.
after detecting another message from the client it enters in forever loop and the string is empty.

I want something similar to a chat, where the client send messages and the server display the message.

So after opening the socket, what should i do to get the message from the client, then display it , then wait for another message?

One other thing that is bugging me is the client http get:

this is the http get

```
GET /iclock/cdata?SN=2182682370001&options=all&pushver=2.1.2&language=80 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.43:8070
User-Agent: iClock Proxy/1.09
Connection: close
Accept: * / *
```

What does it mean when it says connection close? do i need create a new socket every time the client want to send a request?

Try to figure it out, i did some changes on the code, inside the do while i have got this

```
 while ((bytesRcvd = client.Receive(rcvBuffer/*, 0, rcvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None*/)) > 0) 
                    { 
                        totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;
                        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
```

Image:
[image: Wireshark and console app]

so in the image i have got wireshark running and my console app.

according to wireshark the client had tried to send 2 http request, but according to the console it only displayed one...

i want to display the two calls..

a few years ago, i did some exercises about sockets in c language.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
void main(void)
{
  struct sockaddr_in me, from;
  int newSock, sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  int adl = sizeof(me);
  char linha[81];
  bzero((char *) &me, adl);
  me.sin_family = AF_INET;
  me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY ); /* endereco IP local */
  me.sin_port = htons(8450); /* porta local  */
  if (-1 == bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &me, adl))
  {
    close(sock);
    puts("Porta ocupada");
    exit(1);
  }
  listen(sock, 5);
  newSock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &adl);
  close(sock);
  do
  {
    read(newSock, linha, 81);
    puts(linha);
  } while (strcmp(linha, "exit"));
  close(newSock);
}
```

this is in c, so as you can see,after the accept the socket stays open, and the client send the message, it only close the socket when the user send exit to the server...
there may be times where the client doesnt send...but the socket is still open, and when it detects

this is an example of what i want to achive, using the system.net.sockets library,,,

thanks

Comment: You could take a shot at SignalR, seems to fit your need nicely

Comment: i could, but i would like to use the sockets library only, i know it need more work, but isnt it possible?

Comment: Your code should work. It should display everything that the single connected client sends. Can you be more specific about the problem you want to solve?

Comment: i added an image an discribed it...

Comment: HTTP by default doesn't use keep-alive connections - each request-response pair uses a new TCP connection (and thus a new client socket). When the `Receive` method returns zero, it tells you the connection has been closed. All in all, you should use something higher up the abstraction level unless you want to learn a lot of new things about how TCP and HTTP works (and how to properly handle that in C#). Using e.g. `HttpListener` will save you a lot of trouble. Or have a look at OWIN for a full-fledged in-process web server :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of sockets: The socket that you use to listen (it is never connected) and the sockets that correspond to connections (each socket represents one connection).

Accept returns you a connected socket to the client that was just accepted. Each call to Accept accepts a new , independent client.

If you want to handle more than one client at a time (which is almost always required) you must ensure that a call to Accept is pending at all times so that new clients can be accepted.

A simple model to achieve this is to accept in a loop forever and start a thread for each client that you accepted:

```
while (true) {
 var clientSocket = listeningSocket.Accept();
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => HandleClient(clientSocket));
}
```

Comment: But what if the client is the same? i do understand that for it to handle various client i will need to use threads. but it this case for now it is just one client that in intervals of 1 second is sending some requests, like the example in c above it is possible to open the socket and maintaining it open until the client sends exit...today i will try to create a sample example like a chat i try to create multiple clients and see how it goes..

Comment: Was that 2nd request really on the same TCP connection? As I said your code works in the sense that it drains one connection. It will never move on after the first connection, though, because you just read indefinitely.; The word client is not very precise. You should probably say connection. TCP has no understanding of what a client, or HTTP, is.

Comment: thanks for the help.. so i have the server socket and the client socket, the server socket is listening for new connections, and when it detects it creates a new socket..with client=server.accept(); after that i need to add the thread in order to handle the client socket right?

Comment: Yes. Conceptually, this is quite simple. Be prepared to continue making mistakes, though, because sockets are really hard. I hope this is just a learning exercise for you and not production code. In production, prefer higher-level solutions like web-services. Hope the issue is resolved for you.

Comment: thanks, during this weekend i am gone try to do an test progrma, by creating a server an client and put it working, then i will past here the problems that i found..and the complete exercise once finish and working correctly.

Comment: I recommend that you ask a new question for any specific issues that might come up. That's a better way to get helped.

Comment: so one thind i did find is that the client send a [fin,ack] package, and what that means is that after sending the data, the client closes the connection, but the socket is still open from the server to client. so i still can send message to the clint. after sending the response i too should close the socket.Or is it possible that the socket is waiting for a response..but because it doesnt receive a response, it closes after let say 10 seconds?

Comment: i note that the fin ack package only appears a few seconds after the http post is sent..15 to 20 seconds ? is the host waiting for a responde?

Comment: Looks like HTTP keep-alive. Shutdown the connection when you have nothing left to send. Then close.

Comment: is this case i cant control the client socket, because it is a terminal(hardware), so the client send http request, and i need to send data according to the request..after that close the connection from the server side..

Answer (score 1):

It might very well be that the client closes the connection.

To detect this on the server side you need to test the result of the call to `Receive()` against `0`.

From [MSDN's documentation on `Receive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (emphasis by me):

> If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method will read as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter. **If the remote host shuts down** the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, **the Receive method will complete immediately and return *zero* bytes**.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, every time client disconnects from server/listener, this will be registrered on server as SocketException - client has forcibly disconnected. What I do at the moment is just try to catch this and "nicelly" ignore it (log/display some sort of message or run an action to inform the user about this).

Have a look at your code, slightly refactored. Try to run it and see what is happening. I have added some comments to explain a bit. Hope this will help.

There is also class called [TcpListenner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET you can use to implement behavior you require.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace SimpleListener
{
    class Program
    {
        const int PORT = 8070;
        const int BACKLOG = 5;

        static Socket socket;
        private static byte[] rcvBuffer;
        private static int bytesRcvd;
        private static string message;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                StartListener();

                Listen();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowMessage(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void StartListener()
        {
            try
            {
                //Initialize socket and start listenning
                socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
                socket.Listen(BACKLOG);

                ShowMessage("I'm listenning now..");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void Listen()
        {
            try
            {
                rcvBuffer = new Byte[256];
                bytesRcvd = 0;
                message = string.Empty;

                //Start listnening/waiting for client to connect
                while (true)
                {
                    var client = socket.Accept();
                    ShowMessage("Client with IP " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected!");

                    //Client has connected, keep receiving/displaying data
                    while (true)
                    {
                        SocketError rcvErrorCode;

                        bytesRcvd = 0;
                        message = string.Empty;

                        bytesRcvd = client.Receive(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                        if (rcvErrorCode != SocketError.Success)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Client with IP " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " disconnected!");
                            break;
                        }

                        message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);

                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " - " + message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void ShowMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems your experience doesn't include proper TCP behaviour - graceful shutdown of a TCP connection is signaled by getting a `Read` that returns zero - that's telling you the connection is closed. Only when you try to do something with that socket again is that exception raised, and it's basically telling you you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have adjusted the code. Thank you for your comment, I've learn something.